# crystal report selecting wrong month in date parameter

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a Crystal report that has an StartDate and an EndDate parameters.  My problem is that when I select November in the calendar, it jumps to December.  This happens only with November, any other month is selected perfectly.  I wonder if anybody has had this type of issue before and able to fix it.  Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Tag your question with the specific version that you are using, please.  Does this happen in the design environment, in BOE, your application?

Comment: Hi Craig.  I am using Crystal XI.  This report is used from the design environment.

Comment: I've never encountered this.  Ensure that you've applied the latest service pack/hot fix.

Comment: I have never seen anything like it either.  Thanks for your reply anyway.  Hopefully someone else will have a tip on how to fix it.

Comment: Are you trying 11/31?

Comment: No, it happens when I select any day within November from 1 to 30.  It jumps to select the 12th month instead of the 11th.

Comment: I never seen this type of issue may be issue with crystal reports itself.. if possible try any fix pack or unistall and re install the crystal reports.

Comment: Well the weird thing is that so far that is the report with that problem that have been reported to me. All the rest seem to be fine.  I am thinking of maybe recreating that report from scratch if I cannot figure out what is causing that.

Comment: Can you check the SQL query to see what is being passed?